# How can I add UIToolbar to UIPickerView without using UITextField?

Tags: swift

I have used `UIPickerView` without `UITextField`. After user tap on button, `UIPickerView` will display.

Anyway, I have no idea how to dismiss `UIPickerView`. I have tried to set `inputAccessoryView` with `UIToolbar` but the complier said it's get-only property.

My code:

```
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolbar.isTranslucent = true
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(RegisterViewController.pickerDoneButton))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(RegisterViewController.pickerCancelButton))

    toolbar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: true)
    toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    pickerView.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

> Error: Cannot assign to property: 'inputAccessoryView' is a get-only property

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Try to add subview to the UIPickerView**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like UIPickerView is not letting its children receive touch events. If you want to add toolbar to pickerview without textfield you can create a top level container UIView to hold both toolbar and picker view like this:

```
let picker = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - 260, width: view.frame.width, height: 260))

// Toolbar
let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.monthdoneButtonAction))
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelClick))

let barAccessory = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: picker.frame.width, height: 44))
barAccessory.barStyle = .default
barAccessory.isTranslucent = false
barAccessory.items = [cancelButton, spaceButton, btnDone]
picker.addSubview(barAccessory)

// Month UIPIckerView
monthPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barAccessory.frame.height, width: view.frame.width, height: picker.frame.height-barAccessory.frame.height))
monthPicker.delegate = self
monthPicker.dataSource = self
monthpickerData = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
monthPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
picker.addSubview(monthPicker)
```